# what is the benefit of defining a $scope interface

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Learning typescript to use with Angularjs. I see an interface is declared for the scope as in
[ref](https://github.com/anchann/angularjs-typescript-e2e/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/TasksController.ts)

```
interface TasksControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
    tasks: Task[];
}

class TasksController {
    constructor($scope: TasksControllerScope, taskService: TaskService) {
        taskService.get().then((tasks: Task[]): void => {
            $scope.tasks = tasks;
        });
    }
}
```

what is the benefit of this?

Answer (score 0):

This will help the designer know that there is a variable `tasks` available that he can bind to style from html.

PS: I (as well as the angular team with `controller as` syntax) actually recommend putting the Controller on the scope : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1